# I am a beginner and for some reason this does not work I am using visual studio

Tags: c++

So I am a beginner and for some reason this still give me the undeclared identifier error and the system cannot find specified file errro I would be grateful if someone would answer me this

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* about the error messages (when posting question about build errors, copy-paste them (as text) into the body of the question)? Because I would rather suspect that the compiler would complain about you not including `"stdafx.h"` first. When using Visual Studio with precompiled headers (the default) then the first non-comment and non-empty line in every source *must* be the inclusion of `"stdafx.h"`.

Answer (score 3):

When using `visual studio`, this line `#include "stdafx.h"` needs to be at the top of your code **when using pre-compiled headers**.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is only true if you're using pre-compiled headers.

Comment: @MrEricSir yeah, just added that to the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.